# General term of recurrence relation

Tags: recurrence-relations

Find the general term of the following recurrence relation:

$$a_{1} = 2$$

$$a_{n+1}  = \frac{2a_{n} - 1}{3}$$

I've tried to find the first few terms:

$$a_{1} = 2$$
$$a_{2} = \frac{2 \cdot 2 - 1}{3} = 1$$
$$a_{3} = \frac{2 \cdot 1 - 1}{3} = \frac{1}{3}$$
$$a_{4} = -\frac{1}{9}$$
$$a_{5} = -\frac{1}{27}$$

but can't see any pattern, especially considering the first 2 terms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$ 3a_{n+1}=2a_n-1 \tag{1}$$
and we may try to get rid of the inhomogeneous term $-1$ by a suitable substitution.
For instance, by setting $a_n=b_n-1$, we get $b_1=3$ and
$$ 3b_{n+1}=2b_n \tag{2} $$
from which $b_n = 3\cdot\frac{2^{n-1}}{3^{n-1}}$ readily follows. The general term of the original sequence is so:
$$ a_n = \color{red}{3\cdot\frac{2^{n-1}}{3^{n-1}}-1}.\tag{3}$$

Comment: Thank you for your time and answer! Could you suggest a source for further reading on this topic?

Comment: @Ziezi: these slides http://nms.lu.lv/wp-content/uploads/2016/04/21-linear-recurrences.pdf should be a good starting point.

Comment: The slides are great! (just to note) The link at the end is broken.

Answer (score 0):

Following your (@Jack D'Aurizio) suggestion, here is what I understood:

The given *recurrence relation*: $3a_{n} = 2a_{n-1} - 1$, with *initial conditions*: $a_{1} = 2$ is a *$1^{st}$ degree linear non-homogeneous recurrence relation*.

Solution:

We are searching for solution<sup>1</sup> of the form: $a_{n} = b_{n} + h_{n}$ (1), where $h_{n}$ is the sequence satisfying the *associated homogeneous recurrence relation* and $b_{n}$ is a solution which is similar to $f(n)$.

1.The associated homogeneous recurrence relation is: $3h_{n} = 2h_{n-1}$ and its *characteristic equation* is: $3r - 2 = 0$ or $ r = \frac{2}{3}$ and the solution is:

$$h_{n} = \alpha_{0} (\frac{2}{3})^{n-1} $$

From the initial conditions: $a_{1} = \alpha_{0} (\frac{2}{3})^{1} = 2$ or $\alpha_{0} = 3$, so the solution of the homogeneous recurrence is:

$$h_{n} = 3 (\frac{2}{3})^{n-1} $$

2. In our case $b_{n} = -1$ and from (1) we have:

$$a_{n} = 3 (\frac{2}{3})^{n-1}  - 1$$

---

<sup>1. $a_{n}$ satisfies both the recurrence relation and the initial conditions.</sup>

<sup>2. $f(n)$ - function depending only on $n$.</sup>